# Scala Dispatch How to enable SNI

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

We have a website that makes 'get' requests to a server. We have now been informed that we need to add SNI information to the requests. We use Dispatch for our http calls.

How do I enable SNI in Dispatch?

scala: 2.11.7
Dispatch: 0.11.2

Answer (score 1):

After investing half a day googling and trying a few things, we decided to switch to play ws which took less than an hour.

On a sidenote, dispatch is an ugly library. It has function calls that make it seem like the library was written three thousand years ago in Egypt.